# how can i sort a groovy list selected from database using specific field

Tags: groovy

how can i sort a groovy list selected from database using specific field
example:
book table srted by subject

Comment: It would be very helpful with a code example so we can get a feel for what you are doing. As it stands we have no way of knowing if you are using Grails, GSQL, pure JDBC or if you're just trying to sort an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it purely in groovy (without grails), you can do something like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test-db"
def dbUser = "test"
def dbPassword = "test"
def dbDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)

sql.eachRow("select * from book order by subject asc") { row ->
    println "${row}\n"
}
```

In grails, you have a few choices.  You can use HQL:

```
Book.findAll("from Book order by subject asc")
```

Or one of the flavors of dynamic finders:

```
Book.findAllByName(name, [sort: 'subject', order: 'asc'])
```

Or a criteria search:

```
Book.withCriteria { order("subject", "asc") }
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure Groovy (without Grails) you can do:

```
bookList.sort{it.subject}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`def books = Book.list(sort:"subject", order:"asc")`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html)

EDIT: You can also have a [default sort order](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.3%20Default%20Sort%20Order) in your domain class:

```
static mapping = {
    sort = 'subject'
}
```

Comment: You're assuming he's using Grails, though it wasn't mentioned in the question